# Display image from different funtion in kivy python

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, kivy-language

Hi im trying to build a scanner which takes an image and on clicking submit button it should return resultant image in new screen, this is where im till now, help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
import time
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

Builder.load_string( '''
<CameraClick>:
orientation: 'vertical'
Camera:
    id: camera
    resolution: 500,500
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Click'
        on_press: root.capture()
        on_release: camera.play = False
    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.capture()
        on_release: camera.play = False
''')

class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
def capture(self):
    '''
    Function to capture the images and give them the names
    according to their captured time and date.
    '''
    camera = self.ids['camera']
    print("camera down")
    print(type(camera))
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
    print("Captured")
    return Image(source='hey.png')

#  def release(self):
    

class CameraApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CameraApp().run()
```

Comment: function assigned to button (or menu) can't return value because there is no object which could get this value. You should assign it to global variable  or class variable - ie. `self.image` - and other class/function should get it from this variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you click button then `Kivy` runs assigned function but it doesn't get returned value - it wouldn't know what to do with returned value.

You have to assign value to global variable or to class (with `self.`) and other function has to get value from this variable.

```
def capture(self):
    self.image = Image(source='hey.png')

def other_function(self):
    do_something(self.image)
```

If `other_function` can be executed before `capture` then it is good to create this variable at start with some default value - ie. `None`

```
class CameraClick(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.image = None
```

and then you can check if `capture` was executed

```
def other_function(self):

    if self.image:
        do_something(self.image)
    else:
        print('Image not captured yet')
```

---

If you want to use the value in different classes then you may have to assign it to global variable - eventually if it possiblem you can send instance of one class to other class as arguments

```
camera_click =  CameraClick()
OtherClass(camera_click)
```

and other class can keep it and later it can use it to get image

```
class OtherClass():

    def __init__(self, camera, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.camera = camera


    def some_function(self):
       
        if self.camera.image:
            do_something(self.camera.image)
        else:
            print('Image not captured yet')
```

---

BTW: Sometimes classes may have the same `parent` and then `OtherClass` can use

```
 self.parent.camera_click.image
```